# Regular expression pattern for the date format 1st mon/month yyyy and mon/month, 1, yyyy

Tags: regex

I have  regex pattern for the following date formats but they are not working as expected

1st mon/month yyyy(which should match date of type 2nd April 1785,1st April 1999,3rd April 2000,4th Jan 1999)

mon/month, 1, yyyy(which should match date of type November 2, 2000,Nov 4, 2000)

1st mon/month yyyy - `\s?(?:0?[1-9]|[1,2][0-9]|3[0-1])(?:nd|rd|th|st)?(?:[\s|,|]?\s?)(?:[Jj]an(?:uary)?|[Ff]eb(?:ruary)?|[Mm]ar(?:ch)?|[Aa]pr(?:il)?|[Mm]ay|[Jj]une|[Jj]uly|[Aa]ug(?:ust)?|[Ss]ept(?:ember)?|[Oo]ct(?:ober)?|[Nn]ov(?:ember)?|[Dd]ec(?:ember)?)\s\d{4}`

mon/month, 1, yyyy - `\s?(?:[Jj]an(?:uary)?|[Ff]eb(?:ruary)?|[Mm]ar(?:ch)?|[Aa]pr(?:il)?|[Mm]ay|[Jj]une|[Jj]uly|[Aa]ug(?:ust)?|[Ss]ept(?:ember)?|[Oo]ct(?:ober)?|[Nn]ov(?:ember)?|[Dd]ec(?:ember)?)(?:[\s|,]?\s?)(?:0?[1-9]|[1,2][0-9]|3[0-1])(?:[\s|,]?\s?)\s\d{4}`

Both the formats are taking more than 4 digits in a year say I can give November 2, 200000000 and it is matching successful it should accept only 4 digits

Comment: What behavior are you expecting, and what actual behavior are you receiving? Please post examples.

Comment: Thanks Nick I updated the description

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `\b` to the ends of both your regexes. This forces the date to break at a "word boundary", meaning if you have more than four digits, the regex won't match.

- `ab\d{4}` will match `ab1234` and will "match" `ab123456`, up to the `4` - I'm assuming you want this second case to fail because it's badly formatted, and has too many numbers.
- `ab\d{4}\b` will NOT match `ab123456`, but will match `ab1234`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick it worked .One help I have a reqular expression which match the date format dd/mm/yyyy i.e 25/10/1988.Regular expression pattern:- \s?(?:0?[1-9]|[1,2][0-9]|3[0-1])(?:/)(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:/)(?:\d{4}) but for my requirement there is a string in front of the date i.e  date is 25/10/1988 I need to validate with regular expression pattern.Please suggest some pattern

Comment: Glad to help! Please consider accepting the answer of it addresses your question, so future readers know what works. If you know the string in front of the date has no numbers in it, you can put `[^\d\n]+` in front of the regex to capture the string. If you know the exact words that will be there, you can put `date is ` in front of the regex to validate the exact string. Else, `.*?` is a possible option to capture all the content before the date. Good luck!